# Jenkins on Windows: How to encrypt the httpsKeyStorePassword in jenkins.xml?

Tags: ssl, password, jenkins

I'm running Jenkins, currently 2.89.3 on Windows, and have managed to configure SSL (...hooray!...).

Problem now is that I want to encrypt the `-httpsKeyStorePassword` defined in `jenkins.xml`, but despite all my Google-skills, I have not been able to figure out how to do it. Actually it might be that the answer is "no can do", ref. [JENKINS 38090 - Configure encrypted password for java keystore in /etc/sysconfig/jenkins](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-38090) which seems related and says:

> It is not possible to enter encrypted or hashed passwords for java keystore. 
>   Variable: `JENKINS_HTTPS_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD` in `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins`
>   only able to read "plain text" password!

Anyone able to either confirm that the above Jenkins issue is still valid, but most hopefully point to some documentation (which I should have found) explaning how to do it.